# While loop won't exit C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
while(!int.TryParse(menuChoice, out menuNumber))
{                
     AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid choice, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);
     menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();     
}
while (menuNumber > 3 | menuNumber < 1)
{
     AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid Number, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);
     menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();               
}
```

The code above checks to see if the user entered a valid value for int and another check that sends an error if the value entered is an int but not in a certain range.The error im having is when ever a number that is higher then 3 or lower then 1 it triggers the error and tells you to select a valid choice and if you enter a valid choice after the prompt it will still give you the same error prompt

Comment: you need to reassign `menuNumber`

Comment: Daniel is correct.  Your while loop is checking for a change in menuNumber, but only menuChoice ever changes (in the second while loop)...

Comment: Step through the code line by line in a debugger. You should see something interesting happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your immediate problem, I would suggest a little refactoring is in order.  Use 1 loop with a boolean for the exit condition.  Inside you test the repsonse and either set the boolean to true or print the error message:

```
bool correct = false;
while (!correct)
{
    if (int.TryParse(menuChoice, out menuNumber) && (menuNumber <= 3 && menuNumber >= 1))
    {
        correct = true;
    }
    else
    {
        AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid choice, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);
        menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

You can go 1 step further and get rid of the parsing.  Simply check if the first character entered is in the proper range:

```
bool correct = false;
string menuChoice = "";
char choice = '\0';
while (!correct)
{
    menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    choice = menuChoice[0];
    if (choice >= '1' && choice <= '3')
    {
        correct = true;
    }
    else
    {
        AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid choice, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like:

```
    public int GetChoice(int MinRange, int MaxRange)
    {
        do
        {
            string menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            int menuNumber = -1;
            if (int.TryParse(menuChoice, out menuNumber))
            {
                if (menuNumber >= MinRange && menuNumber <= MaxRange)
                    return menuNumber;
            }
            AlertMessage($"You have enetered an invalid Number, please select a correct option! ({MinRange}-{MaxRange})", ConsoleColor.Red);
        } while (true);
    }
```

instead, and call it like:

```
int menuChoice = GetChoice(1,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!int.TryParse(menuChoice, out menuNumber))
        {                
         AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid Number, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);           
            menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();     
    }
```

in this loop ,it will not stop until u enter string or any data type that is not integer so u need to make condition that you put for second loop togther

```
   while(!int.TryParse(menuChoice, out menuNumber) ||( menuNumber > 3 || menuNumber < 1))
     {                
         AlertMessage("You have enetered an invalid Number, please select a correct option! (1-3)", ConsoleColor.Red);
            menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();     
    }
```

so it will stop when you enter right number (1-3)
because if you enter string condition will be true and if you enter number not inside (1-3) condition will be true